# How to change Bootstrap panel-body in LESS file?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm new with LESS and trying to customize Bootstrap but I've been able to create a common panel class that inherits all of the panel-primary colors. I'm doing that so that if I wanted to change all of my panels to say panel-default I just make that change in one place and they all get the new class.

What I would like to do is change the body's background color to a slight gray. I thought i could do it like the following but it's not picking up the color.

```
.vtc-panel{
    .panel;
    .panel-primary;
    .panel-body{
        background-color:gainsboro!important;
    }    
}
```

This is how I'm using the class.

```
<div class="vtc-panel">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <span class="punch-employee-info">Name: </span><span class="punch-employee-info-value">@Model.EmployeeName</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <span class="punch-employee-info">Employee #: </span><span class="punch-employee-info-value">@Model.EmployeeNumber</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
```

Comment: `gainsboro !important` looks like you forgot a space there. See if that helps any.

Comment: good catch but unfortunately that didn't seem to work.

Comment: Your code renders as `.vtc-panel .panel-body` so it should be working.

Comment: @IE5Master....I was wrong. That was it, I just had to clear the cache. Make that and answer and I'll mark it for you.

Comment: It wasn't that. Space doesn't matter in that case.

Comment: maybe I just needed to clear the cache? Either way, I put the space before the !important, saved, cleared cache, refreshed and it's good now. I'll have to remember to clear cache next time before posting a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your CSS

```
.vtc-panel{
   .panel;
   .panel-primary;
   .panel-body{
       background-color:gainsboro !important;
    }    
}
```

Also, try clearing your cache. This might help out some.

This should do the trick.